# codeigniter dynamic menu creation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create dynamic menu with database.

The ***Controller*** is menu.php

```
  <?php
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'EN';

class Menu extends CI_Controller {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model("menu_model");
}

public function index()
{
    $data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory('$lang');
    $data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory('$lang');

    $this->load->view('vwHeader',$data);//Left Menu
}
}
?>
```

the ***Model*** is menu_model.php

```
<?php
 class Menu_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

function getCategory($lang){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category';
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    
    return $result;
    }
    
    
}

function getSubCategory($lang){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM subcategory';
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
   if($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
   return $result;
    }
    
}

}
?>
```

the ***View*** is vwHeader.php

```
<?php


           foreach($category->result() as $menu)
{
echo "<ul style='margin-left: 148px;margin-top: 15px;'>";
   echo "<li style='float: left;


height: 57px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;'><a class=\"sf-with-ul\" href=\"category/".$menu->urlcategory."\">".$menu->namecategory."</a>";
   /*check whether sub menu is there if so first print <ul> then <li><a>*/
   if(count($subcategory->result()) > 0 && is_array($subcategory->result()))
   {
         echo "<ul class=\"sub-menu\">";
        foreach($subcategory->result() as $key=>$submenu)
        {
          if ($menu->idcategory == $submenu->idcategory){
           echo "<li><a href=\"category/".$submenu->urlsubcategory."\">".$submenu->namesubcategory."</a></li>";
            }
         }
        
        
        
    }
    else
        {
        echo "<ul style='display:none'>";
        echo "</ul>";
        } 
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
     echo "</ul>";
}

                    ?>
```

Now the error is,

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: category
>
> Filename: views/vwHeader.php
>
> Line Number: 38
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\application\views\vwHeader.php on line 38

how can i solve that????

Comment: If you search with that error message you would get lots of result at google.Try to read [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Remove single quotes that wrap `$lang` variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no value in `$lang`. Assign value or pass as empty.Empty will get all data.(Below code is without `$lang`)

In Model

```
function getCategory()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM category");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);
    if(!empty($count))
    {
        return $result;
    }
}

function getSubCategory()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM subcategory");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);
    if(!empty($count))
    {
        return $result;
    }

}
```

In controller

```
$data['category']= $this->menu_model->getCategory();
$data['subcategory']= $this->menu_model->getSubCategory();
```

In View

```
foreach ( $category as $new_category )
{
    echo '<a href="">'. $new_category;.'<a>';//your rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are fetching object.

And in your code, if your database has records you are returning object else nothing returns.

Change

```
if($result->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    return $result;
    }
```

to

```
return $result
```

Avoid condition of number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

See, first you need to correct some lines in your code:-

1. for `return $result;` use this `return $result->result()`
2. use `foreach($category as $menu)` instead of `foreach($category->result() as $menu)` and `foreach($subcategory as $menu)` instead of `foreach($subcategory->result())`